# Convert exe video to avi

Tags: converters, exe

Yes,I know there is no exe video,but there is screen recording [software](http://www.screen-record.com/screen2exe.htm) that save the videos as SWF or EXE for better compression ratio (as they say )

for swf it won't be a problem since there is a lot of swf readers out there,

But for exe it can be problem for a lot of reasons

like i can't read it on other platforms except for windows

can't upload it online

can't edit it

and also i don't trust executable files

So how can i convert those executables videos to AVI (or any other format ) without having to execute the file on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In either case, the trouble you're having is that you are not working with an actual video.  You are working with an executable file that is playing a series of images.  It's not the same thing as an actual video stream that uses CODECs that can be converted.

So, there is really no way to convert that, short of doing some sort of screen capture of the video playing back.

Comment: That's a shame,Then i will run the video on a virtual machine to fix the executable files trust issue ,but i will still have the problem of not being able to convert-edit-share it

Comment: No...  You won't.  And with support for Flash (SWF) dropping like mad, that's not going to help much either.  You need to get that into an actual video stream before you can do anything with it.  One thing you could try, is upload the SWF to YouTube.  Then, download the MP4.  That might work...